Undo remove css done in a parent theme
I have one theme that is removing a specific css file that is not needed for it.
layout/default_head_blocks.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <remove src="mage/calendar.css"/>
</head>

I now have a child theme that inherits the above theme. Is there a way to undo this remove?

In Child Theme, you'll need to follow these steps:

Create a Magento_Theme folder in your child theme.
Inside Magento_Theme, create a layout folder.
Within the layout folder, create a default_head_blocks.xml.

Add code:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    </head>
</page>

Now, run the command php bin/magento c:f and check your changes.
